# Is it good or necessary to use Blobs when running machine learning algorithms with big data

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

I know what I can either upload my data files to the azure ml (as new datasets) or I can use Blobs (and read data within ML experiment). I wonder if particularly one of them is recommended when training machine learning models and creating prediction-related ML solutions.

My goal of using Azure is to cluster users based on a various of features. I have a large dataset (~ 50GB). I wonder if you have any recommendations.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

As stated at [Azure Machine Learning Frequently Asked Questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-faq): "For datasets larger than a few GB, you should upload data to Azure Storage or Azure SQL Database or use HDInsight, rather than directly uploading from local file."

Also please note the maximum sizes of datasets for modules in the Machine Learning Studio. These limits are listed as a part of the same FAQ linked above.